# How would I pull the content of a CMS page into a static block?

Tags: php, templates, magento, content-management-system, render

I want to pull the content of a CMS page into my static block, if you know of a way to do this I would be grateful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but it should work. If you have the unique ID of the cms page (not the identifier):

```
$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page');
$page->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$page->load($pageId);
```

Otherwise if you have the page's identifier (i.e. URL key), use something like this:

```
$urlKey = "url_key";
$page->load($urlKey,'identifier');
```

Then finish with:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('cms');
$processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor();
$html = $processor->filter($page->getContent());
return $html;
```

**== EDIT ==**

Added the template parsing steps as suggested by Alan

Comment: This code isn't going to run the content through the processing class that swaps in directive tag contents (see my answer above/below)

Comment: good point, thanks Alan. Using the cms helper to render the page would do that I guess, so it should be possible to pick out that step...

Comment: This really helped me get what I needed accomplished, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Do it the other way round. Create your content in a static block and [include it in a page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/cms/markup_tags#block_type_modulepackage_classname_template_pathtotemplate.phtml), or other static blocks.

Comment: That is not what I asked and actually doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Not the answer the original poster wanted, but +1 for useful information. In a start from scratch world all your content should be Static blocks pulled into CMS pages via CMS static block widgets

Answer (score 3):

There's no way (that I know of) to do this out of the box.

However, as the static block editing interface allows you to insert **widgets** into static blocks, I'd implement a widget that renders out the contents of a CMS page.  I have [a basic implementation](http://alanstorm.com/2011/projects/magento/Widget_CMS_Page_Content-1.0.0.tgz) I've been playing with, but have been too busy to flesh out.  It's functional, but wouldn't be super performance if you tried to insert a large number of widgets during any one http request.  Feel free to give it a try; any feedback is appreciated.

If you're interested in how to ro programmatically render out a CMS page, checkout the `Mage_Cms_Block_Page::_toHtml()` method.

```
    $helper = Mage::helper('cms');
    $processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor();
    $html = $processor->filter($this->getPage()->getContent());
    $html = $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() . $html;
    return $html;
```

The call to `$this->getPage()` returns a `cms/page` model. The extra code above is necessary,as it passes the page through the filters that replace the directive tags (`{{...}}`)